# Data augmentation for Tensorflow Object Detection API with polygon bounding box

Tags: python, polygon, object-detection-api, bounding-box, data-augmentation

I want to generate a lot of data from my dataset and save on disk. Then use this generated data for object detection. Is there any way to generate data with polygons bounding boxes and then forward them for object detection task?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are many annotation tools that support polygon bounding boxes. Here are some:

https://github.com/ryouchinsa/Rectlabel-support

https://github.com/buni-rock/Pixie

https://github.com/UniversalDataTool/react-image-annotate